# Getting error while using 'circle-color' data driven styling in Mapboxgl.js & GeoJSON, but working fine with default color

Tags: javascript, ajax, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to create a map, put data points using GeoJSON and Mapbox. 
It works fine when I am using a default color code for all points, but when I try to use data driven styling to put different colors for different property values It is giving errors. 
I am using mapboxgl.js.

I get the following errors in Chrome Inspect:

```
net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
exports.getJSON @ ajax.js:33
evented.js:111 Error
at XMLHttpRequest.r.onerror (ajax.js:18)
```

Please help!
Here are my GeoJSON and HTML files.

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoicml0YW1iaGFyYSIsImEiOiJjajZuNGZjNHUwNHgxMzNwc29hZ2ZkbmRvIn0.4kTuXEpbJBeoN3jCp3pfwQ';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9',
    center: [-121.403732, 40.492392],
    zoom: 10
});
map.on("load", function() {
    map.addSource('pH', {
        'type': 'geojson',
         'data': 'test.json'
    });
    map.addLayer({
        id: 'heat-map',
        type: 'circle',
        source: 'pH',
        paint: {
            // 'circle-color': '#f1f075',
            'circle-color': {
                property: 'value',
                 stops: [
                    [6, '#f1f075'],
                    [10, '#e55e5e']
                ]          
            },
            "circle-radius": 6,
            'circle-opacity': 0.8
        },
    });
});
```

GeoJSON file:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": { "value": "7" }, 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-121.415061, 40.506229]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": { "value": "8" }, 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-121.505184, 40.488084]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": { "value": "9" }, 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-121.354465, 40.488737]
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is due to the fact that your `value`s are in the geojson as strings not numbers. When I changed them to numbers as below your example code worked for me

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": { "value": 7 }, 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-121.415061, 40.506229]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": { "value": 8 }, 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-121.505184, 40.488084]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": { "value": 9 }, 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-121.354465, 40.488737]
        }
    }]
}
```

If you still get the AJAX error you may need to run a local server ( you can do this with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in your project folder and then load `localhost:8000/path/to/index.html` in your browser)

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Still is there a way to do the same using string values, because my json files have all the string values.

Comment: You could use a categorical function, but you'd have to assign a color value to each distinct `value` string because you cannot interpolate between string values. We will soon release a new feature called `expressions` that will enable you to call a `to-number` function on your data values (it is currently available on the `master` branch on github https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js)

Comment: Thanks, 
I am converting csv file to GeoJSON data using 
csv2geojson.csv2geojson(csvString, {
    latfield: 'LATFIELDNAME',
    lonfield: 'LONFIELDNAME',
    delimiter: ','
}, function(err, data) {
});
It Automatically saves all the values as string datatypes, 
Is it possible to define a datatype here itself? I looked up on the internet but couldn't find any explanation or use.
(Sorry, I know I went off-topic. I am trying to use to-number from the link you shared but it will take me some time to understand how to do it)